# calculate The maximum likelihood estimator of parameter $\mu$ according to $T$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample of $N(\mu,1)$. if $T=\sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i<0)}$ how can I calculate The maximum likelihood estimator of parameter $\mu$ according to $T$. ($\Phi$ is 
Standard normal distribution function)

Comment: The question is garbled. T (the number of observations that are negative) is not the MLE. It is not based on the sufficient statistics. Maybe with yet another edit someone can figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

First we can write $P(X < 0) = P(X - \mu < - \mu) = \Phi(-\mu)$, and so $T \sim$ binomial$(n, p = \Phi(-\mu))$.  The likelihood function on observing $T = t$ is then just the binomial mass function at the point $t$,

$$
L(\mu) = \binom{n}{t} \Phi(-\mu)^t [1 - \Phi(-\mu)]^{n - t} .
$$

But the maximum likelihood estimate of the success probability for a sample of Bernoulli trials is just the sample mean, so we know this function is maximized when $\Phi(- \mu) = t / n$, which means $\hat{\mu}_\text{MLE} = - \Phi^{-1}(t / n)$.